# Layout issues with XIB in Xcode 5 (after upgrading app)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, uiview

I have worked on this application, done 2 years back, using XIB's and `Autosizing`.

Now, I've upgraded this app (*in Xcode 5*) & I need to make changes according to iPhone 5 (4") and iPhone 4, 4s (3.5")

I've tried to put Margin layouts but these are not making any difference.

[image]

I've created quite a few apps before using similar techniques with out any complication but in this app, the view in iPhone4 has a black cut at the top and bottom of the screen.

![enter image description here][2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is not related to `AutoSizing`.
You're just missing the `640x1136` launch image (*i.e. **`Default-568h@2x.png`***).

[image: Launch Images]

Add it and your app should go full screen.

***PS***: This happened to me when I created an iOS7 project in Xcode 5 and deleted `Images.xcassets` from the project targets.

---

[reference](http://coronalabs.com/blog/2012/09/19/faq-wednesday-iphone-5-and-ios-6/)